# Deleting Comments with Facebook Comments Box plugin?

Tags: facebook, comments

I have everything working good, I can and check all the comments left on my Site and be able to moderate them but i dont see an option to actually Delete other users comments, the only option i can find is to Hide there comments from everyone except there friends.

Is there no way to actually delete comments from other users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is for abuse tracking the comments are "hidden" rather than "deleted" just in case those comments could be used as evidence in a court case.